# Parallel execution of localhost tasks in Ansible

Tags: performance, ansible, performance-testing

I'm using `community.vmware.vmware_guest_powerstate` collection for Ansible to start VMs.

The problem is the time it takes for 1 VM can be 2-5 sec, which makes its very inefficient when I want to start 50 VMs ...

Is there any way to make it in parallel?

The playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  collections:
    - community.vmware
  vars:
    certvalidate: "no"
    server_url: "vc01.x.com"
    username: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.env', 'API_USER', default=Undefined) }}"
    password: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.env', 'API_PASS', default=Undefined) }}"
  tasks:
    - name: "setting state={{ requested_state }} in vcenter"
      community.vmware.vmware_guest_powerstate:
        username: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.env', 'API_USER', default=Undefined) }}"
        password: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.env', 'API_PASS', default=Undefined) }}"
        hostname: "{{ server_url }}"
        datacenter: "DC1"
        validate_certs: no
        name: "{{ item }}"
        state: "powered-on"
      loop: "{{ hostlist }}"
```

This is Ansible's output: (every line can take 2-5 sec ...)

```bash
TASK [setting state=powered-on in vcenter] ************************************************************************************************************
Monday 19 September 2022  11:17:59 +0000 (0:00:00.029)       0:00:08.157 ****** 
changed: [localhost] => (item=x1.com)
changed: [localhost] => (item=x2.com)
changed: [localhost] => (item=x3.com)
changed: [localhost] => (item=x4.com)
changed: [localhost] => (item=x5.com)
changed: [localhost] => (item=x6.com)
changed: [localhost] => (item=x7.com)
```

Comment: Try [async](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_async.html#asynchronous-actions-and-polling).

Comment: @VladimirBotka async will just keep ansible running without waiting, but the process will still start them 1 by one ... (so last vm in a huge list - still suffers .... )

Answer (score 0):

> *... the time it takes for 1 VM can be 2-5 sec, which makes its very inefficient when I want to start 50 VMs ...*

Right, this is the usual behavior.

> *Is there any way to make it in parallel?*

As already mentioned within the comments by Vladimir Botka, [asynchronous actions and polling](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_async.html) is worth a try since

> *By default Ansible runs tasks synchronously, holding the connection to the remote node open until the action is completed. This means within a playbook, each task blocks the next task by default, meaning subsequent tasks will not run until the current task completes. This behavior can create challenges.*

You see it in your case in the task and in a loop.

Probably the **Best Practice** to address the use case and to eliminate the cause is to enhance the [module code](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.vmware/blob/main/plugins/modules/vmware_guest_powerstate.py).

According the documentation [`vmware_guest_powerstate` module – Manages power states of virtual machines in vCenter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/vmware/vmware_guest_powerstate_module.html) and source [ansible-collections/community.vmware/blob/main/plugins/modules/vmware_guest_powerstate.py](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.vmware/blob/main/plugins/modules/vmware_guest_powerstate.py#L225), the parameter `name:` takes one name for one VM only. If it would be possible to provide a list of VM names `"{{ hostlist }}"` to the module directly, there would be one connection attempt only and the loop happening one the Remote Node instead of the Controller Node (... even if this is running `localhost` for both cases).

To do so one would need to start with [`name=dict(type='list')`](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.vmware/blob/main/plugins/modules/vmware_guest_powerstate.py#L231) instead of `str` and implement all other logic, error handling and responses.

**Further Documentation**

Since the community `vmware_guest_powerstate` module is importing and utilizing additional libraries

- [pyVmomi library](https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi/)
- [pyVmomi Community Samples](https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi-community-samples)

---

Meanwhile and based on

**Further Q&A and Tests**

- [How do I optimize performance of Ansible playbook with regards to SSH connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73181784/6771046)

I've setup another short performance test to simulate the behavior you are observing

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Gather subdirectories
    shell:
      cmd: "ls -d /home/{{ ansible_user }}/*/"
      warn: false
    register: subdirs

  - name: Gather stats (loop) async
    shell: "stat {{ item }}"
    loop: "{{ subdirs.stdout_lines }}"
    loop_control:
      label: "{{ item }}"
    async: 5
    poll: 0

  - name: Gather stats (loop) serial
    shell: "stat {{ item }}"
    loop: "{{ subdirs.stdout_lines }}"
    loop_control:
      label: "{{ item }}"

  - name: Gather stats (list)
    shell: "stat {% raw %}{{% endraw %}{{ subdirs.stdout_lines | join(',') }}{% raw %}}{% endraw %}"
    register: result

  - name: Show result
    debug:
      var: result.stdout
```

and found that adding `async` will add some additional overhead resulting into even longer execution time.

```bash
Gather subdirectories ------------------------ 0.57s
Gather stats (loop) async -------------------- 3.99s
Gather stats (loop) serial ------------------- 3.79s
Gather stats (list) -------------------------- 0.45s
Show result ---------------------------------- 0.07s
```

This is because of the "short" runtime of the executed task in comparison to "long" time establishing a connection. As the documentation pointed out

> *For example, a task may take longer to complete than the SSH session allows for, causing a timeout. Or you may want a long-running process to execute in the background while you perform other tasks concurrently. Asynchronous mode lets you control how long-running tasks execute.*

one may take advantage from `async` in case of long running processes and tasks.

In respect the given answer from @Sonclay I've performed another test with

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Gather subdirectories
    shell:
      cmd: "ls -d /home/{{ ansible_user }}/*/"
      warn: false
    register: subdirs
    delegate_to: localhost

  - name: Gather stats (loop) serial
    shell: "stat {{ item }}"
    loop: "{{ subdirs.stdout_lines }}"
    loop_control:
      label: "{{ item }}"
    delegate_to: localhost
```

whereby a call with

```bash
ansible-playbook -i "test1.example.com,test2.example.com,test3.example.com" --forks 3 test.yml
```

will result into an execution time of

```bash
Gather subdirectories ------------------------ 0.72s
Gather stats (loop) -------------------------- 0.39s
```

so it seems to be worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead...

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  collections:
    - community.vmware
  vars:
    certvalidate: "no"
    server_url: "vc01.x.com"
    username: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.env', 'API_USER', default=Undefined) }}"
    password: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.env', 'API_PASS', default=Undefined) }}"
  tasks:
    - name: "setting state={{ requested_state }} in vcenter"
      community.vmware.vmware_guest_powerstate:
        username: "{{ username }}"
        password: "{{ password }}"
        hostname: "{{ server_url }}"
        datacenter: "DC1"
        validate_certs: no
        name: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
        state: "powered-on"
      delegate_to: localhost
```

Then run it with your hostlist as the inventory and use forks:

ansible-playbook -i x1.com,x2.com,x3.com,... --forks 10 play.yml