# Ansible - Run a task once over a list

Tags: loops, ansible

I'm trying to write a task that should be executed once over a list, for example:

```yaml
- name: Create something that has an attribute with more than one values
  some_module:
    some_attribute: "{{ item }}"
  run_once: true
  loop:
    - a
    - b
```

But the task written like this will be executed two time, like

```yaml
- name: Create something that has an attribute with more than one values
  some_module:
    some_attribute: "a"
  run_once: true

- name: Create something that has an attribute with more than one values
  some_module:
    some_attribute: "b"
  run_once: true
```

What I like to obtain is this:

```yaml
- name: Create something that has an attribute with more than one values
  some_module:
    some_attribute:
      - a
      - b
  run_once: true
```

where "some_attribute" is also a list.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: I don’t understand. What is the question, and the desired result?

Comment: I believe that depends on the module being used. `run_once` is meant to be run on only the first host. So provide a reproducible example in order to help you better.

Comment: Why would you want to achieve that? The 'loop' is perfectly designed for this use case. Why swim against the tide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *But the task written like this will be executed two time*

Right, that is expected behavior and working as it was designed.

> *How can I achieve this? ... where `some_attribute` is also a list.*

You can't, unless the module which you are like to use is supporting `list` as `some_attribute`. A good example for this is the [`yum` module – Manages packages with the `yum` package manager](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/yum_module.html) and the [Notes](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/yum_module.html#notes)

> *When used with a `loop:` each package will be processed individually, it is much more efficient to pass the list directly to the `name` option.*

You'll find some more examples and test playbooks with measurements under the my Similar Q&A links. They'll show the behavior in more detail and explain why this is.

**Similar Q&A**

- [How do I optimize performance of Ansible playbook with regards to SSH connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73181784/6771046)
- [Parallel execution of localhost tasks in Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73782713/6771046)

---

*... unless you are not providing more background information, details and describe what you try to achieve, at least the module name, a better answer can't be given.*

Comment: and "pass the list directly to the name option." was the solution... it was easier than i thought. thanks